# MySQL Error #1054

Tags: mysql

When uploading data to mysql I get this error:

> #1054 - Unknown column 'aid' in 'field list'  "

This is the part in which I'm getting error #1054

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `admin` (
  `aid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `aname` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `amail` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `anumber` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `aip` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `apass` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `atime` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `city` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `fb` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `other` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`aid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `admin`
--

INSERT INTO `admin` (`aid`, `aname`, `amail`, `anumber`, `aip`, `apass`, `atime`, `city`, `fb`, `other`) VALUES
(1, 'M SaeeD KhaN NiaZi', 'mianwali@gmail.com', '03437517173', '::1', 'niazi', '2015-07-14 23:00:00', 'MiAnWaLi  PAKisTaN', 'www.facebook.com', 'BhAnGi  BhAi');
```

Comment: `aid` is auto-increment. Do **not** provide a value. The DB does it.

Comment: Please format your question. At the moment its really hard to read.

Comment: your query working fine

Comment: @juergend But that wouldn't account for the error. In any case, a data dump would always include the values.

Comment: Yes. Works fine for me too... http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/63ba6/1

Comment: @juergend This is not correct, it is allowed to specify the value for an auto increment field in an insert statement. The provided value will be inserted into that field.

Comment: @NiAZi Just out of curiosity, can you pls run a show create table for the admin table? Just in case it does not have an aid field. For example, the target database had an admin table before, which does not have aid field.

Comment: AnyOne Of You Know How To Fix iT ???

Comment: i used This Database in one my website , it worked fine ...  my website hosting was suspended .... So Now , iam trying to upload this database for my new website but its giving this error ...

Answer (score 0):

Your query works fine, as long as the table does not exist yet:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `admin` (
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You can verify current table in a number of ways, e.g.:

```
show columns from admin;
show create table admin;
select * from admin limit 1;
```

You can also add a `show warnings;` statement right after the `create table` one:

```
mysql> show warnings;
+-------+------+------------------------------+
| Level | Code | Message                      |
+-------+------+------------------------------+
| Note  | 1050 | Table 'admin' already exists |
+-------+------+------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: When i upload it on a hosting site , i get this error :d




""Error
SQL query:

--
-- Dumping data for table `admin`
--
INSERT INTO  `admin` (  `aid` ,  `aname` ,  `amail` ,  `anumber` ,  `aip` ,  `apass` ,  `atime` ,  `city` ,  `fb` ,  `other` ) 
VALUES ( 1,  'M SaeeD KhaN NiaZi',  'mianwali@gmail.com',  '03437517173',  '::1',  'niazi',  '2015-07-14 23:00:00',  'MiAnWaLi  PAKisTaN',  'www.facebook.com',  'BhAnGi  BhAi' ) ;


MySQL said: Documentation

#1054 - Unknown column 'aid' in 'field list' ""

Comment: Yes, I already read your question (and code in comments is not more readable). Can you explain how exactly did my answer fail to address it so I can improve it?

Comment: i wanna say that it points error in    " Dumping data for table 'admin' "

Comment: Sorry, I still don't get it. Is your comment specifically related to my answer or you're just posting a new different question? Is there anything I haven't explained properly?